# Evaluating a correlated subquery in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble getting my head around evaluating correlated subqueries. An example is using a correlated subquery in SELECT so that GROUP BY isn't needed:

Consider the relations:

```
Movies : Title, Director Length
Schedule : Theatre, Title
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT S.Theater, MAX(M.Length)
FROM Movies M JOIN Schedule S ON M.Title=S.Title
GROUP BY S.Theater
```

Which gets the longest film that every theatre is playing. This is the same query without using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.theater,
    (SELECT MAX(M.Length)
    FROM Movies M
    WHERE M.Title=S.Title)
FROM Schedule S
```

but I don't understand how it quite works.

I'd appreciate if anybody could give me an example of how correlated subqueries are evaluated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually...

To understand this, first ignore the bit about correlated subquery.

Consider the order of operations for a statement like this:

```
SELECT t.foo FROM mytable t
```

MySQL prepares an empty resultset. Rows in the resultset will consist of one column, because there is one expression in the SELECT list. A row is retrieved from mytable. MySQL puts a row into the resultset, using the value from the foo column from the mytable row, assigning it to the foo column in the resultset. Fetch the next row, repeat that same process, until there are no more rows to fetch from the table.

Pretty easy stuff. But bear with me.

Consider this statement:

```
SELECT t.foo AS fi, 'bar' AS fo FROM mytable t
```

MySQL process that the same way.  Prepare an empty resultset. Rows in the resultset are going to have *two* columns this time. The first column is given the name fi (because we assigned the name fi with an alias). The second column in rows of the resultset will be named fo, because (again) we assigned an alias.

Now we etch a row from mytable, and insert a row into the resultset. The value of the foo column goes into the column name fi, and the literal string 'bar' goes into the column named fo.  Continue fetching rows and inserting rows into the resultset, until no more rows to fetch.

Not too hard.

Next, consider this statement, which looks a little more tricky:

```
SELECT t.foo AS fi, (SELECT 'bar') AS fo FROM mytable t
```

Same thing happens again. Empty resultset. Rows have two columns, name fi and fo.

Fetch a row from mytable, and insert a row into the resultset. The value of foo goes into column fi (just like before.) This is where it gets tricky... for the second column in the resultset, MySQL *executes* the query inside the parens. In this case it's a pretty simple query, we can test that pretty easily to see what it returns. Take the *result* from that query and assign that to the fo column, and insert the row into the resultset.

Still with me?

```
SELECT t.foo AS fi, (SELECT q.tip FROM bartab q LIMIT 1) AS fo FROM mytable
```

This is starting to look more complicated. But it's not really that much different. The same things happen again. Prepare the empty resultset. Rows will have two columns, one name fi, the other named fo. Fetch a row from mytable. Get the value from foo column, and assign it to the fi column in the result row. For the fo column, execute the query, and assign the result from the query to the fo column. Insert the result row into the resultset. Fetch another row from mytable, a repeat the process.

Here we should stop and notice something. MySQL is picky about that query in the SELECT list. Really really picky. MySQL has restrictions on that. The query must return exactly one column. And it cannot return more than one row.

In that last example, for the row being inserted into the resultset, MySQL is looking for a *single* value to assign to the fo column. When we think about it that way, it makes sense that the query can't return more than one column... what would MySQL do with the value from the second column? And it makes sense that we don't want to return more than one row... what would MySQL do with multiple rows?

MySQL will allow the query to return zero rows. When that happens, MySQL assigns a NULL to the fo column.

If you have an understanding of that, your 95% of the way there to understanding the correlated subquery.

Let's look at another example. Our single line of SQL is getting a little unweildy, so we'll just add some line breaks and spaces to make it easier for us to work with. The extra spaces and linebreaks don't change the meaning of our statement.

```
SELECT t.foo AS fi
     , ( SELECT q.tip
           FROM bartab q
          WHERE q.col = t.foo
          ORDER BY q.tip DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS fo
   FROM mytable t
```

Okay, that looks a lot more complicated. But is it really?  It's the *same* thing again. Prepare an empty resultset. Rows will have two columns, fi and fo. Fetch a row from mytable, and get a row ready to insert into the resultset. Copy the value from the foo column, assign it to the fi column. And for the fo column, execute the query, take the single value returned by the query to the fo column, and push the row into the resultset. Fetch the next row from mytable, and repeat.

To explain (finall!) the part about "correlated".

That query we are going to run to get the result for the fo column. That contains a *reference* to a column from the outer table. `t.foo`.  In this example that appears in the WHERE clause; it doesn't have to, it could appear anywhere in the statement.

What MySQL does with that, when it runs that subquery, it *passes in* the value of the foo column, into the query.  If the row we just fetched from mytable has a value of 42 in the foo column... that subquery is equivalent to

```
         SELECT q.tip
           FROM bartab q
          WHERE q.col =   42
          ORDER BY q.tip DESC
          LIMIT 1
```

But since we're not passing in the literal value of 42, what we're passing in is values from the row in the outer query, the result returned by our subquery is "related" to the row we're processing in the outer query.

We could be a lot more complicated in our subquery, as long as we remember the rule about the subquery in the SELECT list... it has to return exactly one column, and at most one row. It returns at most one value.

Correlated subqueries can appear in parts of the statement other than the SELECT list, such as the WHERE clause. The same general concept applies. For *each row* processed by the outer query, the values of the column(s) from that row are *passed in* to the subquery. The result returned from the subquery is *related* to the row being processed in the outer query.

---

The discussion omits all the steps before the actual execution... parsing the statament into tokens, performing the syntax check (keywords and identifiers in the right place). Then performing the semantics check (does mytable exist, does the user have select privilege on it, does the column foo exist in mytable). Then determining the access plan. And in the execution, obtaining the required locks, and so on.  All that happens with every statement we execute.)

And we're going to not discuss the kinds of horrendous performance issues we can create with correlated subqueries. Though the previous discussion should give a clue. Since the subquery is executed for *every* row we're putting into the resultset (if it's in the SELECT list of our outer query), or is being executed for *every* row that is accessed by the outer query... if the outer query is returning 40,000 rows, that means our correlated subquery is going to be executed 40,000 times. So we better well make sure that subquery executes fast. Even when it executes fast, we're still going to execute it 40,000 times.

Comment: VERY Good and thorough explanation, thanks alot for this!

Comment: What would happen if the correlated part of the query appears before, in the select clause, e.g.:

 `SELECT ( SELECT q.tip
            FROM bartab q
           WHERE q.col = t.foo
           ORDER BY q.tip DESC
           LIMIT 1
         ) AS fo,
  t.foo AS fi
      
 FROM mytable t`

Comment: In that case, the only difference would be the order of the columns in the result set. Apart from that, there's no difference. The resultset would be equivalent. BUT.. sometimes the order of expressions does make a difference. But this isn't such a case. Where the order of expressions makes a difference is when we are evaluating expressions involving user-defined variables, and assigning values to those same user-defined variables. The order of the operations is significant, (The MySQL Reference Manual warns against relying on the *undefined*  behavior with this usage user-defined variables.)

Comment: @user3186023: I tried to lay out in my explanation a basic framework for understanding what happens when we execute a SELECT statement, the operations that MySQL performs. When we understand what the execution plan is *doing*, it helps us understand how a particular statement is going to be processed. (Note that I only explained the operation of some very simple statements. And I omitted  some important steps that occur earlier in statement processing: parsing tokens, the syntax check, the semantics check, evaluating possible access paths and join methods, and selecting an execution plan),

Comment: @user3186023: In your previous comment... the reference to t.foo could be omitted from the SELECT list, the query could return just one column,  the result from the correlated subquery. And that would have no affect on what is returned in that column... the correlated subquery would be evaluated exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

From a conceptual standpoint, imagine that the database is going through each row of the result without the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Theater, S.Title
FROM Schedule S
```

And then, for each one of those, running the subquery for you:

```
SELECT MAX(M.Length)
FROM Movies M
WHERE M.Title = (whatever S.Title was)
```

And placing that in as the value.  Really, it's not (conceptually) that different from using a function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Theater, SUBSTRING(S.Title, 1, 5)
FROM Schedule S
```

It's just that this function performs a query against another table, instead.

I do say conceptually, though.  The database may be optimizing the correlated query into something more like a join.  Whatever it does internally matters for performance, but doesn't matter as much for understanding the concept.

But, it may not return the results you're expecting.  Consider the following data (sorry sqlfiddle seems to be erroring atm):

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  Title varchar(255),
  Length int(10) unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (Title)
);

CREATE TABLE Schedule (
  Title varchar(255),
  Theater varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (Theater, Title)
);

INSERT INTO Movies
VALUES ('Star Wars', 121);
INSERT INTO Movies
VALUES ('Minions', 91);
INSERT INTO Movies
VALUES ('Up', 96);

INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('Star Wars', 'Cinema 8');
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('Minions', 'Cinema 8');
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('Up', 'Cinema 8');
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES ('Star Wars', 'Cinema 6');
```

And then this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  S.Theater,
  (
    SELECT MAX(M.Length)
    FROM Movies M
    WHERE M.Title = S.Title
  ) AS MaxLength
FROM Schedule S;
```

You'll get this result:

```
+----------+-----------+
| Theater  | MaxLength |
+----------+-----------+
| Cinema 6 |       121 |
| Cinema 8 |        91 |
| Cinema 8 |       121 |
| Cinema 8 |        96 |
+----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, it's not a replacement for GROUP BY (and you can still use GROUP BY), it's just running the subquery for each row.  DISTINCT will only remove duplicates from the result.  It's not giving the "greatest length" per theater anymore, it's just giving each unique movie length associated with the theater name.

PS: You might likely use an ID column of some sort to identify movies, rather than using the Title in the join.  This way, if by chance the name of the movie has to be amended, it only needs to change in one place, not all over Schedule too.  Plus, it's faster to join on an ID number than a string.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I will read and digest this in the morning. Much appreciated. When you say "for each one of those..." do you mean each tuple returned from that query?

Comment: To add, the thing thats confusing me is in my query, S.title isn't outputted in the outerquery, so when it compares S.title to M.title in the inner query, I'm confused as to what S.title is referring to in this case.

Comment: Yes, for each row of the result.

Comment: Think of it in the context of each row in the result.  It starts with row 1.  Whatever S.Title would have been (if you had selected it) in that row, that's what it uses in the subquery.  In row 2, it again starts with a new query, but with whatever row 2's S.Title would have been.

Comment: Is there any chance you could supply me with a minimal example, even with just 2 tuples in each relation, and briefly show the steps? I think this would help me get my head around it, if it isn't a lot to ask for.

Comment: DISTINCT is only going to apply to the results.  I didn't realize you didn't know that, let me edit with an example to clarify.

Comment: I was being stupid there actually - I've deleted that comment as I've understood that aspect of the query.

Comment: Okay, there's an example now.  You can see it really is the same as if you selected each row from the table, ran the subquery, and then ran DISTINCT afterward.

Comment: Okay - that examples cleared everything up for me - it doesn't actually return the longest showing for a theater, which is what I thought it did.

Comment: Yes, but it *is* performing the MAX.  If there were multiple movies with the same title (remakes?) then it would give the highest value.  So it's a bit different from a join, still.

Comment: Right - it's performing the max amongst remakes of movies, but not the longest showing movie currently showing in a theater, which is what the group by query does right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109616/discussion-between-todd-christensen-and-user3186023).